Is asymptotically normal variable $o(n^p)$ a.s. for $p>1$
Is it true that if $X_n\to_d \mathcal N(0,1)$ then $X_n=o(n^p)$ a.s. for any $p>1$?
I want to show that given $\epsilon$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|X_n|>\epsilon n^p)<\infty$. I use the fact that for any $\delta>0$, when $n$ is sufficiently large, $P(|X_n|>\epsilon n^p)<2\Phi(-\epsilon n^p)+\delta$. There will be infinite $\delta$ added up so I cannot proceed.

Consider $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure. By arranging $1_{(\frac {i-1} {2^{n}}, \frac i {2^{n}}]}$, $i \le 2^{n}, n\ge 1$ in  a sequence  we get $(E_n)$ such that $P(E_n) \to 0$ but $1_{E_n}(\omega)$  has infinitely many $1$'s for every $\omega$. If $X \sim N(0,1)$ then the sequence $X+n^{p}1_{E_n}$ gives  a counter-example since this converges in probability to $N(0,1)$.
